# Não consigo conectar o vuejs no Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Veja a página:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <h1>@{{ msg }}</h1>
        </div>


        <script src="js/vue/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vue/dist/vue.js" ></script>
        <script src="js/axios/dist/axios.js" ></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Esses arquivos JavaScript estão na pasta public.**

Eu consegui conectar o Bootstrap, mas por que não consegui conectar os arquivos JavaScript?

Comment: Qual erro aparece no console quando carrega essa página? E como está a hierarquia das pastas..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia!
O Laravel já traz por padrão uma implementação do VueJs já toda configurada para funcionar, o jeito mais fácil de fazer o vue funcionar é usar essa implementação. Se você verificar em Resources/Assets você verá os subdiretórios css, js e sass. Dentro do js você verá o subdiretório component com um exemplo. Para utilizar essa impementação você deve digitar no diretório raiz da sua aplicação `npm install`, será então instalado o LaravelMix. Parece um pouco complicado, mas está bem explicado na documentação do Laravel nesses links [Frontend Sacaffolding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/frontend) e [Compiling Assets](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix) que fala mais detalhadamente do assunto. Depois do `npm install` você pode rodar `npm run dev` criar uma rota para o arquivo resources/views/vue.blade.php que é um arquivo de exemplo do VueJs configurado no Laravel. Sendo assim todo o seu código deve ficar em resources/assets/js/component e sempre depois de alguma alteração você deve rodar `npm run dev` para compilar o código para o arquivo public/js/app.js (esse é o único arquivo que você deve importar para o seu HTML), tudo isso e feito de forma automática rodando o `npm run dev`.
Sugiro fortemente que você utilize esses recursos pois estão firmemente integrados com Blade e facilita muito a programação.
Boa sorte!